# MVC, View Model and [Required]

Tags: forms, validation, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a setup with a Single View Model that is used for multiple Forms and my Validation is causing my problems.

**Question 1**
Can i use a Single View Model and only validate the fields used in the form?

I have a View Model

```
    public class KundeOrdreVM : IPanelVM
    {
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string ItemEAN{ get; set; }
    }
```

In my View i have two forms (Code Simplified for this example)

```
<form action="/CreatePhone" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">                      
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    <input type="submit" value="Create Phone">
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form action="/CreateItem" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">                       
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemEAN)
    <input type="submit" value="Create Item">
</form>
```

Each Form uses a single field from the shared ViewModel.

My Problem is that i want to make both fields [Required], but only if the user is posting the Form that uses that field.

Is there any way to make this work, while reusing the same ViewModel?

**Question 2**
If I have to use multiple ViewModels, as input for each Form, is there a good design practice guide for how i can Work with Multiple ViewModels in a single View?

I would dislike having to make alot of @Html.RenderPartial for each form on my page. The Forms are closely linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to forms with different requirements, it's to separate ViewModels. Usually ViewModels have a 1:1 relation with the view and 1:n relations are quite uncommon.

One reason for this is, that one of you two views may get a requirement change in future. If you would add this new field to the ViewModel, this will also affect your other view using the same ViewModel.

Initially this may look like more work, but later on it's easier to apply changes when the requirements change.

Reuse ViewModels in multiple views only when they do exactly same thing and when requirement for one changes has to be reflected to all other views, for example `LoginViewModel` where you have different views to login, like login field in the navigation bar, that appears everywhere when a user is logged in and an explicit page where the user is redirected to, when trying to access a protected page.

Comment: I was afraid this was the Case.
How then, do we handle a case where i have 5 Buttons on my Page, each button is a separate Form and each form takes a single Input field.
Do i create 5 ViewModels and then a single ParentViewModel to hold the 5?

Comment: Not sure I understand how the ParentViewModel fits into this. Is the PhoneNumber/ItemEAN or why else would you be required to add them one by one rather than (via separate buttons/forms) instead of one single form. Is it to capture the users intent (i.e. when using event sourcing)? From the above code it looks like each button is tied to one action, so you'd just expect one viewmodel for that one action. What's the ParentViewModel's purpose in this case?

Comment: The situation is that i have an Order Controller and a single page that handles functions about Orders. On that page you can create a new order if you have a Phone Number or you can Add items to the list if you have an Item EAN. Both buttons are places next to each other and the order you use them is irrelevant. I have done this using 1 ViewModel, 2 Forms, 2 buttons, 2 actions on my Controller. This is causing me this problem and im Unsure of the best design for this situation